# css style not applied because of a parameter passed into the url

Tags: php, html, css, model-view-controller, routes

I'm trying to make my own mvc but i'm facing an error with my css path. When i'm on the home page everything works fine but since I navigate into other page, the css path change to mywebsite/**articles**/css/style.css and i don't know how to fix this if anyone can help me. Thank you in advance, here is my code:

**index.php**

```
<?php


define('ROOT', str_replace('index.php', '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));

require_once ROOT. 'models/Model.php';
require_once ROOT.'models/Controller.php';


$url = explode('/', $_GET['url']);

if($url[0] !== ''){
    if(file_exists('controllers/'.ucfirst($url[0]).'.php')){
        $controller = ucfirst($url[0]);
        $action = isset($url[1]) ? $url[1] : 'index'; 
        require_once ROOT.'controllers/'.$controller.'.php';
        $controller = new $controller();
        if(method_exists($controller, $action)){
            unset($url[0]);
            unset($url[1]);
            call_user_func_array([$controller, $action], $url);
        }else{
            http_response_code(404);
        }
    }else{
        http_response_code(404);
    }
}else{
    require_once(ROOT.'controllers/Articles.php');
    $controller = new Articles();
    $controller->index();
}
```

**Class Controller**

```
<?php

abstract class Controller{
    public function loadModel(string $model){
        require_once ROOT.'models/'.$model.'.php';
        $this->Article
        $model = new $model();
        return $model;
    }

    public function render(string $file, $data= array()){
        extract($data);
        ob_start();
        require_once(ROOT.'views/'.strtolower(get_class($this)).'/'.$file.'.php');
        $content = ob_get_clean();
        require_once(ROOT.'views/layout/base.php');
    }
}
```

**on my base.php template**

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

**EDIT**
I finally succeed in adding to my root file

```
define('SCRIPT_ROOT', 'http://localhost/EdelweissMagazine');
```

and

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo SCRIPT_ROOT.'/css/style.css';?>">
```

Comment: How bout setting absolute path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
<link href="{{ asset('/css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: I don't understand how it was supposed to works, it doesn't work ..